# Instagram get posts by tag-name

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am working on a web app and I need to get posts from Instagram by certain hashtag

I used the api found here https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/

but it behaves unexpectedly it only works for one hashtag, if I tried with another one it just return empty array

ex1: `https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/firstTag/media/recent?access_token=MYACCESSTOKEN`

ex2: `https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/secondTag/media/recent?access_token=MYACCESSTOKEN`

where `MYACCESSTOKEN` is my access token.

for ex1 it return expected response but for ex2 it returns :

```
`{
  "pagination": {
  "deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"
  },
  "data": [],
  "meta": {
  "code": 200
  }
}`
```

Comment: are you in sandbox mode ?

Comment: yes I am on sandbox mode

Comment: then you will only see your posts in API response, you posts a pic with the secondTag and that will be in response. once u go live , all data will be in response

Comment: Thanks for help, but I am afraid I didn't understand your comment!

Comment: if you post a photo to instagram using your account with the 2nd hashtag, and then use API to get that hashtag, you will see your photo only in API response. this is how it works in sandbox mode

Comment: Yes I know that ... my question is why I can't see it even in the API response?

Comment: may be YOU have not posted a photo with that hashtag ? have you ?

Comment: A I posted hundreds of photos woth many hashtags an just one hashtag is working!